# Windows, c++ - Gnuplot as child process, cannot get data from stdout

Tags: c++, windows, gnuplot, stdout

I want to use Gnuplot from a C++ program in Windows. I launch Gnuplot (v5.0) as a child process from C++, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx.

Writing to the process `stdin` with `WriteFile` works and I can send commands to gnuplot and it plots OK; however, I also need to read Gnuplot's output back. When trying to read the `stdout` of the process:

- `ReadFile` blocks.
- `PeekNamedPipe` always returns 0 bytes available to be read.

When I launch another executable, for example "cmd.exe", instead of "gnuplot.exe", `PeekNamedPipe` returns a number of bytes available, and `ReadFile` reads data as expected. For me, this means that the code is OK and that somehow, "gnuplot.exe" doesn't write to `stdout`.

Does anyone know if it is possible to read Gnuplot's output like this?

**Edit**

The main goal is to be able to set the terminal to *PNG* and to read back the image data without passing by a temporary file.

Comment: What output do you need? If it's the image data, try `set output '-'` as gnuplot command

Comment: @Christoph: Well, I wanted to read everything, but image data was the most important part. When setting terminal to *png*, using `set output '-'`  didn't work, but not setting output at all (i.e. removing the `set output ` command entirely) worked. I've modified the question so you can answer it. Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction.